# Is it a good idea to have many subdomains in nginx configuration file?

Tags: nginx, subdomain

We are building a platform where users can create their shops and launch them. Every shop will have its own subdomain. And each shop will be served from different folder (Theme). I have decided to go with Nginx for handling subdomains and serve frontend files. But I am worrying about if its good idea to have all subdomain entries in nginx conf file? Is there any other alternative way to do this?

Comment: So you're saying that you're going to add or edit a nginx config file every time a new user registers?  Seems like the wrong approach, but you haven't really given enough info for me to recommend the right approach beyond suggesting that you decouple your infrastructure (nginx) from your application logic (routing to a user's shop).

Answer (score -2):

just create another files check the guide of nginx.com

subfolder = good

subdomain = bad

time out 404 with time 
i